# Doctrine - Need ordering or filtering result with custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, request

I try to order/filter a query with Doctrine but using custom field (ie Field which is not in table).

I have this class "Entry":

```
class SosfEntry
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Groups("id")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     * @Groups("date")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="`date`", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Groups("ref")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ref", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ref;

    /**
     * CUSTOM -------------------------------
     */

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Groups("achievment_percentage")
     */
    protected $achievment_percentage;

/**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAchievmentPercentage(): ? int
    {
        // value between 0 and 100 (here 100 for the example)
        return 100;
    }
```

I'm doing a Doctrine query Builder like this :

```
SELECT a FROM Entry a WHERE a.achievment_percentage = :achievment_percentage ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

But I got this error :

```
Error: Class Entry has no field or association named achievment_percentage.
```

Is there a way to do this directly from the query builder ? Or need I to do some filters manually after the query ?

Comment: You cannot write a query with a field that is not mapped to the database